# What's the difference between $(document).ready() and including a script at the end of the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's the difference between executing a JavaScript function on jQuery's $(document).ready() and including it in the HTML in script tags at the end of the body?

Thanks,

DLiKS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript code inside the `<script>` tags is evaluated (executed) immediately. Note that in this case the page has not been parsed yet (entirely), and the DOM is not yet ready.

JavaScript code inside the jQuery `ready()` callback is evaluated on the DOMContentLoaded event, which occurs after the entire HTML source code has been parsed by the browser.
*About this event:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events

Note that the modern way of defining the ready handler is this:

```
$(function() {
    // code
});
```

Also, check out this SO question, which points out what happens when you don't use the ready callback: [How many JavaScript programs are executed for a single web-page in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735406/how-many-javascript-programs-are-executed-for-a-single-web-page-in-the-browser)

Comment: But is including the script at the end of the body equivalent to executing it on the DOM ready event?

Comment: no, all putting at the bottom does is make the browser not block while the code is loading, particularly from an external script (ex: `<script src='code.jquery.com/script...'>`)

Comment: @Byron Happens to me all the time ... `:)`

Answer (score 3):

- A script at the end of the body will
  run as soon as it is loaded.
- $.ready is executed after the document is complete (any
  linked css is also loaded).
- Body.load runs
  only when all images are loaded as
  well.

Answer (score 1):

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643990/jquery-is-document-ready-necessary) might be helpful.

If you call a function in a script that is placed next to the closing body tag (`</body>`) it's the same thing as using `$(document).ready(function(){});` in the `<head>` section.