# How do browsers parse and interpret JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, browser

How does a browser go about parsing JavaScript it loads from files or inline? I am trying to get at the core of what a browser does. What happens when a page loads and it has `<script>` references to external files, and actual JavaScript on the page too. Any good articles out there?

Comment: Different browsers use different java script engines, such as V8, or spider monkey.

Comment: I imagine they follow some standard. There are some similarities.

Comment: JavaScript code is interpreted, not parsed.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Well you certainly have to parse it before you interpret it

Comment: @dev.e.loper: That standard is ECMA-262: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm.

Comment: There are more standards than ECMA-262, that's actually "Old" javascript. ECMA has published a series of ECMAScript editions. We're moving towards "ES5", the fifth edition. 262 is the third, the fourth was skipped over.

Comment: @Claudiu Ah yes, you certainly do.

Comment: Didn't downvote but don't like overly broad questions "How does technology X work?" when there are quite a few different implementations (browsers in this case).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is defined in the ECMAScript standard.

First the source text (the stuff between the `<script>` tags) is converted into a series of tokens (according to the **Lexical Grammar** of the language):

> The source text of an ECMAScript program is first converted into a
>   sequence of input elements, which are tokens, line terminators,
>   comments, or white space. The source text is scanned from left to
>   right, repeatedly taking the longest possible sequence of characters
>   as the next input element.

Read here: http://es5.github.com/#x7

That series of tokens is treated as a Program, which is then evaluated according to the **Syntactic Grammar** of the language which is defined in chapters 11 to 14 of the ECMAScript standard.

> The syntactic grammar for ECMAScript is given in clauses 11, 12, 13
>   and 14. This grammar has ECMAScript tokens defined by the lexical
>   grammar as its terminal symbols (5.1.2). It defines a set of
>   productions, starting from the goal symbol Program, that describe how
>   sequences of tokens can form syntactically correct ECMAScript
>   programs.

Read here: http://es5.github.com/#x5.1.4

It starts in chapter 14: http://es5.github.com/#x14

---

Note that each `<script>` element represents a separate JavaScript program.
Read here: [How many JavaScript programs are executed for a single web-page in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735406/how-many-javascript-programs-are-executed-for-a-single-web-page-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best description of what a browser does according to the ECMAScript standard [Javascript Closures: Identifier Resolution, Execution Contexts and scope chains](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clIRExSc)