# Passing parameters to new() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js, less

I'm starting to play around with Node.js and specifically with the LessCSS compiler. I saw this call on the source code of the lessc script:

```
new(less.Parser) ({
    paths: [path.dirname(input)].concat(options.paths),
    optimization: options.optimization,
    filename: input,
    strictImports: options.strictImports,
    dumpLineNumbers: options.dumpLineNumbers
}).parse(data, function (err, tree) {
    //...
});
```

What I don't understand is how that `new(lessParser)({})` call works.

From what I've been reading about Object-oriented Javascript I only found examples of new being called like so: `object = new Someting`

So the questions are: how does `new` work in that case? Is it calling `less.Parser` as the constructor? Also, what are the parenthesis (following the new call) executing/returning?

Thanks!

Comment: I think people who use superfluous parentheses after unary operators in order to make them appear as though they are functions are trying to be clever... and failing.

Comment: I'm starting to think that, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted is <del>*exactly*</del> technically (or more or less) the same as doing

```
var parserOptions = {
    paths: [path.dirname(input)].concat(options.paths),
    optimization: options.optimization,
    filename: input,
    strictImports: options.strictImports,
    dumpLineNumbers: options.dumpLineNumbers
};
var parser = new less.Parser(parserOptions);

parser.parse(data, function (err, tree) {
    //...
});
```

But with a few shortcuts and with some parenthesis in "unconventional" places.

JavaScript is a [loose type](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/03/understanding-loose-typing-in.html) language and it is interpreted in [tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501520/how-do-browsers-parse-and-interpret-javascript-code). Which means that it is not too limiting on it's syntax, as long as the grammar is respected.

This let things like :

```
var a = false;
var b = function() { };
var c = false;
new(a || b || c)();
```

be completely valid, and will create a new instance of `b` as it is the first one non-false value defined after the tested variable `a`. (Note that it does not check if `b` is actually a `function`. If `b` was non-false and not a function, the JS engine would throw that it is not a function at run-time.)

Comment: Well, the code Yanick posted is not /exactly/ the same.  In the original code, no objects are being instantiated in the global namespace.

Comment: @IvoC, how so? I just extracted the parts into separate variables.

Comment: @IvoC Why bother commenting without explaining?

Comment: @IvoC Haha really? And who says it's the global context? Either way, I guess it's true. But **functionally**, it's the "same"

Comment: @Yanick. Sorry hit enter too soon / edited my original comment.  I think your answer is largely correct, maybe replace "exactly" by "largely" or "more or less" ?   (because in your example code, "parser" and "parserOptions" are being created in current namespace)

Comment: @IvoC, the only difference with my code is that I *declare* three variables and assign them the data, whereas the original code use data and create an instance of `less.Parser` without assigning it to anything. But I shall precise that part of my answer :) It is *technically* correct that is is *not* exactly the same.

Comment: @YanickRochon thanks! IOW, to confirm I understand, the first parenthesis are not "sending parameters in" to `new`, it's evaluating the `less.Parser` token(?) and using that as the function to be called with the options array.

Comment: @frntk, yes, exactly; `less.Parser` is a token that represent a function constructor, and it sends the options object (not array) :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment really.

The expression `new(less.Parser)({…})` is identical to `new less.Parser({…})`.

The parenthesis are a grouping operator that says "evaluate this expression as a single expression". It is common to use that syntax when the expression in the parenthesis would return a different result without the parenthesis, e.g.

```
var x, y = 7;

alert( typeof (x || y))  // "number"

alert( typeof  x || y )  // "undefined"
```

But since they make no difference to the outcome in the OP, they are pointless and possibly harmful as they change a well known pattern into one that might appear to some as if `new` can be called as a function.